# How to get my search action bar on every activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar, android-search

I was having trouble getting my search activity to work. After lots of help on stack I now Have a search activity with an action bar that can execute a search and show the results to the user.

My problem is that, I wrote all of the functionality into one class based on the help I have gotten. Now that I have learned a lot i realize this is not the best way to do this and I should have my own class for this and am not sure how to transfer my code to easily get the action bar on each activity without adding all the code to every activity.

Here is what my search activity looks currently:

```
public class Search extends Activity implements OnQueryTextListener {

private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("logIN", "starting activity");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return true;
    }

    //get entered search and pop up a toast to show query entered
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit (String query) {

        //toast query 
        Toast.makeText(this, "Searching for: " + query + "...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //make json variables to fill

        // url to make request
        String url = "searchURLWillGoHere";



        try {
            query = URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        String jsonUrl = url + query;



        //todo: get json 
        new ReadJSONResult().execute(jsonUrl);

        return false;
    }

    public class ReadJSONResult extends AsyncTask
    <String, Void, String> {
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            return readJSONFeed(urls[0]);
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {

                //start progress bar
                //requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
                //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);


                ///get 


                JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);

                //acces listview
                lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);

                //make array list for beer
                final List<BeerData> beerList = new ArrayList<BeerData>();



                //get json items
                for(int i = 0; i < json.getJSONArray("data").length(); i++) {

                    String beerId = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"id", json);
                    String beerName = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"name", json);
                    String beerDescription = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"description" , json);
                    String beerAbv = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"abv" , json);
                    String beerIbu = GetBeerDataFromJSON(i,"ibu" , json);
                    String beerIcon = GetBeerIconsFromJSON(i, "icon",json );
                    String beerMediumIcon = GetBeerIconsFromJSON(i, "medium",json );
                    String beerLargeIcon = GetBeerIconsFromJSON(i, "large",json );
                    String beerGlass = GetBeerGlassFromJSON(i, json );
                    String beerStyle = GetBeerStyleFromJSON(i,"name", json );
                    String beerStyleDescription = GetBeerStyleFromJSON(i,"description", json );
                    String beerBreweryId = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "id", json );
                    String beerBreweryName = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "name", json );
                    String beerBreweryDescription = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "description", json );
                    String beerBreweryWebsite = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "website", json );

                    //get long and latt
                    String beerBreweryLat = GetBeerBreweryLocationJSON(i, "longitude", json );
                    String beerBreweryLong = GetBeerBreweryLocationJSON(i, "latitude", json );

                    String beerBreweryYear = GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(i, "established", json );
                    String beerBreweryIcon = GetBeerBreweryIconsFromJSON(i,"large",json);



                    //create beer object
                    BeerData thisBeer = new BeerData(beerName, beerId, beerDescription, beerAbv, beerIbu, beerIcon,
                            beerMediumIcon,beerLargeIcon, beerGlass, beerStyle, beerStyleDescription, beerBreweryId, beerBreweryName,
                            beerBreweryDescription, beerBreweryYear, beerBreweryWebsite,beerBreweryIcon, beerBreweryLat, beerBreweryLong);

                    //add beer to list
                    beerList.add(thisBeer);


                }

                //update listview
                BeerSearchAdapter adapter1 = new BeerSearchAdapter(Search.this ,R.layout.listview_item_row, beerList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);


                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {    
                       @Override
                       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                                int arg2, long arg3) {
                              Intent i = new Intent(Search.this, BeerPage.class); 

                              BeerData beerInfo = beerList.get(arg2);


                              //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,  beerInfo.beerName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                              i.putExtra("myBeerObject",  beerInfo);   
                              i.setClass(Search.this, BeerPage.class);


                              startActivity(i); 



                       } 
                   });

                //end progress bar
                //setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);






            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("ReadBeerDataTask", e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }          
        }
    }

    private String GetBeerDataFromJSON(int position, String whatToGet, JSONObject json ) {
        String whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor = whatToGet;
        int whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData = position;
        String holder = "";
        try{
            holder = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData).getString(whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;
    }


    //get icons
        private String GetBeerBreweryIconsFromJSON(int position, String whatToGet, JSONObject json ) {
            String whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor = whatToGet;
            int whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData = position;
            String holder = "";
            try{
                holder = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData).getJSONArray("breweries").getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("images").getString(whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor);;
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                holder = "N/A";
            }



            return holder;
        }

    //get icons
    private String GetBeerIconsFromJSON(int position, String whatToGet, JSONObject json ) {
        String whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor = whatToGet;
        int whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData = position;
        String holder = "";
        try{
            holder = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData).getJSONObject("labels").getString(whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;
    }

    //get style information
        private String GetBeerStyleFromJSON(int position, String whatToGet, JSONObject json ) {
            String whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor = whatToGet;
            int whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData = position;
            String holder = "";
            try{
                holder = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData).getJSONObject("style").getString(whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                holder = "N/A";
            }



            return holder;
        }

        //get location data
        private String GetBeerBreweryLocationJSON(int position, String whatToGet, JSONObject json ) {
            String whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor = whatToGet;
            int whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData = position;
            String holder = "";
            try{
                holder = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData).getJSONArray("breweries").getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("locations").getJSONObject(0).getString(whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                holder = "N/A";
            }



            return holder;
        }

    //get brewery information
        //get style information
                private String GetBeerBreweryInfoFromJSON(int position, String whatToGet, JSONObject json ) {
                    String whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor = whatToGet;
                    int whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData = position;
                    String holder = "";
                    try{
                        holder = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData).getJSONArray("breweries").getJSONObject(0).getString(whatIsTheKeyYouAreLookFor);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        holder = "N/A";
                    }



                    return holder;
                }

    //get glass
    private String GetBeerGlassFromJSON(int position, JSONObject json ) {

        int whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData = position;
        String holder = "";
        try{
            holder = json.getJSONArray("data").getJSONObject(whereInTheJSONArrayForLoopIsTheData).getJSONObject("glass").getString("name");

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            holder = "N/A";
        }



        return holder;
    }


    //gets the json from the inputed url
    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }        
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }




}
```

Update: I took the suggestion in the comments and used my search.java and went to my beerPage and extended Search:

```
public class BeerPage extends Search
```

I now get the search on the BeerPage but when I try an execute the search it force closes with this error:

```
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:138)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.Search$ReadJSONResult.onPostExecute(Search.java:196)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at com.example.beerportfoliopro.Search$ReadJSONResult.onPostExecute(Search.java:1)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5536)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1074)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-30 10:13:16.357: E/AndroidRuntime(22194):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think the problem is the beer page does not have a list view, but the search page does. Can I make it change to the search page to display the results from the beer page search?

Comment: Create a base activity class containing the code for the search stuff and make any other activity extend that base activity class.

Comment: @Luksprog tried it, and it helped but I am still stuck. Updated info in question

Comment: Probably the `e.getlocalizedMessage()` returns `null`. Use `Log.d("ReadBeerDataTask", "Exception: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());`

Comment: ok that makes it not crash but its not showing the search results. It only shows search results if I search from search.java